# ID increments after each codeception test

Tags: laravel-5, codeception

I'm using Laravel5 module in Codeception and it works great, but I have a problem which is when I run a test model factory inserts data and rolls back it, but it's effect on 'auto increment' property in id column, which is making the id column is very massive, so how to roll back id also not data only?